# How do I register a service with Bonjour?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bonjour

I am trying to start to use Bonjour. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/NetServicesArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001074-SW1) I found a manual how to register a service with Bonjour. The following is written there:

> The network services architecture in
>   Bonjour includes an **easy-to-use**
>   mechanism for publishing, discovering,
>   and using IP-based services.

Well let's see how to register a service. In the very beginning it is written:

> To publish a service, an application
>   or device must register the service
>   with a **Multicast DNS responder**

But how?!?! First of all I do not know what is the Multicast DNS responder. Second, it is not written how do I do it. Where and what should I type? Should I use command line? Should I use some programming languages? What exactly should I type...

Is there an easy way to start to use Bonjour? Well, it was emphasized several times how easy it should be to use it. But I cannot start to use it for several day.

So, can anybody, pleas, help me with that?

Comment: I just found out that Bonjour is a Multicast DNS responder. So, how I use it to register a service. Why it cannot be just one line in the command line?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you confirm you're on MacOSX?

Answer (score 4):

you could use something like

```
mDNS -R myssh _ssh._tcp local 222
```

which would register ssh on a nonstandard port (222).

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mDNS/ shows the list of available parameters and further pointers to other documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line on OSX you can use `mDNS` or its alias `dns-sd`.  I seem to recall that one or other of those also exists builtin to Vista and later.

To do it in a program, you need to go ask again at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good place to start :

```
http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/
```

Comment: Using this link I have downloaded the Bonjour. But I still do not know how to to use it (for example to register a service or to discover available services). On the page you gave me there is a FAQ. Among the questions there is "What should I pass in for the "name" parameter when registering a service?". Bat I have no ideas how to register a service, how to find this "name" parameter or where to write it. I think there is a gap between the very beginning and practical usage of the Bonjour.